# How can I get an input in specific function and then use it in another function from the same class in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have developed a class which gets an array as input and sort it with quicksort algorithm. the algorithm is based on divide and conquer method, so it is recursive.I am trying to set global value and then pass the parameters to partition function as default value, but it doesn't work.
after asking for input, the error below appears.
this is the error:

```
def partition(self, start = gl_start , end = gl_end):
NameError: name 'gl_start' is not defined
```

here is the code

```
class quick:
    def __init__(self,text = input(' Please insert an array: ')):
        global gl_start
        global gl_end
        array = text.split(',')
        gl_start = 0
        gl_end = len(array) - 1
        self.array = array
        self.start = gl_start
        self.end = gl_end
    def partition(self, start = gl_start , end = gl_end):
        pivot = self.array[start]
        left = start + 1
        right = end
        done = False
        while not done:
            while left <= right and self.array[left] <= pivot:
                left += left
            while self.array[right] >= pivot and right >=left:
                right -= right
            if right < left:
                done = True
            else:
                # swap places
                print( "Items swapped: {" + str( self.array[left] ) + ' , ' + str(self.array[right]) + '} ' )
                temp=self.array[left]
                self.array[left]=self.array[right]
                self.array[right]=temp
            # swap start with myList[right]
            print( "Pivotpoint swap : [" + str( self.array[start] ) + '] ----> [' + str(self.array[right]) + '] ' )
            temp=self.array[start]
            self.array[start]=self.array[right]
            self.array[right]=temp
            print( " Updated array is : " + str(myList))
            return right
    def quicksort(self, start = gl_start , end = gl_end):
        if start < end:
            # partition the list
            pivot = self.partition(start, end)
            # sort both halves
            self.quicksort( start, pivot-1)
            self.quicksort(pivot+1,end)
        return self.array


myList = quick()
myList = quick.quicksort()
```

I know I'm stuck with a simple answer. any help would be appreciated
thanks guys!

Comment: Most glaring error is the `text=input(...)`; this would be executed *exactly once* and that value be shared for all cases where the `text` argument is not provided to constructor. You should use e.g. `text=None`; then `if text is None: text = input()` within the `__init__`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use global, you woud use  use self.gl_start etc..to access attributes but that won't fix your error as you cannot use self.gl_start etc.. as args, you should pass the `start` and `len(myList.array) -1` when you call `quicksort` and remove everything from the init bar creating the array:

```
class Quick:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array = input(' Please insert an array: ').split(',')

    def partition(self, start, end):
        pivot = self.array[start]
        left = start + 1
        right = end
        done = False
        while not done:
            while left <= right and self.array[left] <= pivot:
                left += 1
            while self.array[right] >= pivot and right >= left:
                right -= 1
            if right < left:
                done = True
            else:
                # swap places
                print("Items swapped: {" + str(self.array[left]) + ' , ' + str(self.array[right]) + '} ')
                temp = self.array[left]
                self.array[left] = self.array[right]
                self.array[right] = temp
            # swap start with myList[right]
            print("Pivotpoint swap : [" + str(self.array[start]) + '] ----> [' + str(self.array[right]) + '] ')
            temp = self.array[start]
            self.array[start] = self.array[right]
            self.array[right] = temp
            print(" Updated array is : " + str(self.array))
            return right

    def quicksort(self, start, end):
        if start < end:
            # partition the list
            pivot = self.partition(start, end)
            # sort both halves
            self.quicksort(start, pivot - 1)
            self.quicksort(pivot + 1, end)
        return self.array


myList = Quick()
myList.quicksort(0, len(myList.array) - 1)
```

You also need to create an instance and then call the method on the instance not calling `Quick.quicksort`:

```
myList = Quick()
myList.quicksort(0, len(myList.array) - 1)
```

Now a sample run:

```
In [9]: q = Quick()
 Please insert an array: 22,11,3,121,3,55,2,66

In [10]: q.quicksort(0, len(q.array) -1)
Items swapped: {3 , 2} 
Pivotpoint swap : [22] ----> [3] 
 Updated array is : ['3', '11', '2', '121', '3', '55', '22', '66']
Pivotpoint swap : [3] ----> [3] 
 Updated array is : ['3', '11', '2', '121', '3', '55', '22', '66']
Pivotpoint swap : [3] ----> [121] 
 Updated array is : ['121', '11', '2', '3', '3', '55', '22', '66']
Pivotpoint swap : [121] ----> [11] 
 Updated array is : ['11', '121', '2', '3', '3', '55', '22', '66']
Out[10]: ['11', '121', '2', '3', '3', '55', '22', '66']
```

So we have another issue, we are comparing strings not int/float so to fix that we need to cast the input, there is also something wrong in your logic as with strings '22' should come before the 3's so there is definitely a bug in your code.

To cast so the elements you can map to float:

```
self.array = list(map(float,input(' Please insert an array: ').split(',')))
```

The bug I will leave to you to figure out.